# Stubing Figaro with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a problem with stubing Figaro on rspec test.
I have code that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def ce_url_link
    path = Figaro.env.online_url || Figaro.env.root_url + '/online'
    "#{path}/#{ce_code}"
  end
end


describe 'ce_url_link' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  context 'when Figaro.env.online_url is not present' do

    it 'uses Figaro.env.root_url as a path' do
      allow(Figaro.env).to receive(:online_url).and_return(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

And when I add some expectation spec Figaro.env.online_url returns the same what I have in application.yml. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't stubbed `Figaro.env` as a double.

```
describe do
  before do
    stub_const("Figaro", double)
    allow(Figaro).to receive_message_chain(:env, :foo_bar) { :yay }
  end

  it do
    expect(Figaro.env.foo_bar).to eq :yay
  end
end
```